# Getting memory error while creating an numpy array of 1578627

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, keras

Here is the code https://text-share.com/view/90024556

```
# Problem on this line
train_x = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(allWordIndices, mode='binary')
```

This `tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix` creates a matrix of 1578627 and throws a memory error what should i do is there a way to do this in batches `tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you have included sets num words to a miximum. Apply a small maximum to overcome your memory issues.

```
max_words=100000
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=max_words)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @loannis answer, you can first fit tokenizer and then do

```
max_words=100000
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.num_words=max_words
```

This helps you decide what you can and cannot fit into memory.